# internal server error after deleting thumbnails image-style

Tags: 8, media

I have an internal server error on my drupal site only when I log in, when logged out everything is fine.

I was having problems with the default image-styles, they would not work (no thumbnail preview) so I created a new style (thumbnail2), deleted the default thumbnail style and replaced it with thumbnail2 style.

Any ideas how I recover from this?

So 2 problems:
1. get access to admin again
2. get default images styles to work

Server log:
Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: "Route "view.media.media_page_list" does not exist."

Answer (score 0):

After some googling I saw a similar error on Drupal.org

https://www.drupal.org/node/2836162

Check the last few comments. It might be related to Media Entity

Comment: Thankyou, I have looked at this post previously, but I have media_entity and media_entity_image modules installed, I have tried manually disabling them. The problem seems to be that I deleted the default thumbnails image-style, is there anyway to get this back - e.g. via the database?

Comment: Not that I know of out of the box... Just brainstorming here. If you have new installation and just copy paste the relevant records from the config table ?

Comment: I've looked in the config table and I can't find the view.media... not in the current install (because it is missing) and not in a fresh install. I find views.view.block_content and others. I deleted the image-style 'Thumbnails' which is used across the site including in the admin area for giving thumbnail previews. There must be a way to just sneek it back in? Otherwise I'm going to have to do a fresh install and start from scratch :(

Comment: Try "image.style.thumbnail"  and in my case the data bin is :
a:8:{s:4:"uuid";s:36:"69a57e83-4bab-4ed7-93d9-0f41af787642";s:8:"langcode";s:2:"en";s:6:"status";b:1;s:12:"dependencies";a:0:{}s:5:"_core";a:1:{s:19:"default_config_hash";s:43:"cCiWdBHgLwj5omG35lsKc4LkW4MBdmcctkVop4ol5x0";}s:4:"name";s:9:"thumbnail";s:5:"label";s:20:"Thumbnail (100×100)";s:7:"effects";a:1:{s:36:"1cfec298-8620-4749-b100-ccb6c4500779";a:4:{s:4:"uuid";s:36:"1cfec298-8620-4749-b100-ccb6c4500779";s:2:"id";s:11:"image_scale";s:6:"weight";i:0;s:4:"data";a:3:{s:5:"width";i:100;s:6:"height";i:100;s:7:"upscale";b:0;}}}}

Comment: Thanks, so I found image.style.medium, I copied it and renamed it to image.style.thumbnail, clearly too simplistic as the data column displayed NULL rather than BLOB - be easy with me I'm still learning. So Oleg your code is rather confusing for me , the only columns I have are collection(varchar), name (varchar), data(longblob)

Comment: Save the code I pasted to you inside a test.bin file and upload that file with phpmyadmin to the specified column. Let me know if that helps

Comment: I uploaded a file test.bin to the data column, I still get "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later." when I log in

Comment: can you truncate all cache tables ? it might be cache playing here

Comment: I truncated all cache tables, reset apache, same problem, I'm away until next week so I will try again later, if all else fails I'll rebuild from scratch :( thanks for the help

Comment: ok then, success :) if you find the solution please post it here :)

Comment: I gave up and rebuilt the website, lukily not much content as I was still setting it up. Now I still have the origonal problem, I upload a jpg using the field-image type, it and I apply the image style, the source says looks for the /sites/default/files/styles/r_teaser/public/2017_04/image.jpg but the file structure ends at public, no 2017_04 folder is created, permissions are 775, owner and group www-data. Configureation says files are uploaded to sites/default/files, the 2017_04 folder is here, but it is empty!